# To to prevent FileHandler logger from impacting other threads?

Tags: python, django, logging, uwsgi

I've got a custom django admin command and I want to capture the log output for when that command is run and make it available for download in a separate file. Similar to "Console Output" functionality in Jenkins. This command is invoked using django-after-response and I'm running uWSGI.

At the beginning of the admin command, I do this:

```
deploy_log = NamedTemporaryFile()
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)-15s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s")
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(deploy_log.name)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(file_handler)
```

Then at the end of the admin command:

```
logging.getLogger('').removeHandler(file_handler)
```

The problem I'm running into is that when there are multiple 'deploys' running simultaneously, the deploy_log for one thread will have entries from other threads. How do I avoid this?

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no way to avoid it, only write to different log files(with worker ID in the filename)

Comment: @AndreyRusanov it is writing to different log files though. Every "deploy" gets a different NamedTemporaryFile().

Comment: I think I've fixed it by setting "enable-threads = true" in my uwsgi ini file.

Comment: Please put it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found the solution. I had to add the following to my uwsgi vassal ini file:

```
enable-threads = true
```

Now the log files are not getting jumbled together.